# Control browser youtube from sound menu

Tags: sound, menu, youtube

In 13.10 I was able to play and pause youtube playback from the sound menu - that was playing in a browser. Since I switched to 14.04 that feature is gone, instead the youtube button opens a separate youtube browser.

Can I change it back? It was pretty handy to control all audio sources from that menu and having that functionality gone is annoying now...